Giving admin access to specific groups in Cognito
I have a user pool that have multiple groups, One of them I have set as admins and the idea is, they will be able to list, edit, update anything related to other users.
For this purpose I am trying to create an inline policy for the role 
I have given all the access but I am trying to add a condition where only specific groups can have these permissions.
I see global keys but I cant seem to find one for cognito:groups 
How can I make some cognito groups have admin level access
I also tried to give permission to a specific user
{
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cognito-idp:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-1:767397735342:userpool/us-east-1_zIho5p9ue",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:userid": "a4889438-1091-706e-a65e-9140c0a97d61"
                }
            }
        }

but its not working

The conditions supported for policies in Cognito user pool are those three (based on tags) aws:RequestTag/${TagKey} and aws:ResourceTag/${TagKey} and aws:TagKeys or Global conditions keys that you listed in your post and no one of these conditions is based on group.
The membership of a user in a group is an information of that user so if you need to control permissions on users based on their membership, I think what you need is to use the verified permissions.

Thanks let me check that, meanwhile can you please have a look at the 2nd part I just updated?

If your need is just to grant admin of a user pool to a specific set of users, the simple way is to create a role with the specific permissions cognito-idp:admin* and attach it to the specific group but without conditions. if you need to customize the policy with group or user attribute you can use AVP or use cognito identity pool with cognito user pool in this last case you can use attributes in IAM policies like cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub and cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud
